# Sumar contenido de relaciones en laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Tengo unas relaciones de las que quiero obtener el resultado de una suma al final.

Mis relaciones son las siguientes:

**PERSONAS**:

```
  public function cuentaCorriente()
 {
    return $this->hasOne('SisInventario\CuentaCorriente', 'idpersona', 'idpersona');
 }
```

**CUENTA CORRIENTE**:

```
 public function pagoCorriente()
{
    return $this->hasMany('SisInventario\PagoCorriente', 'idcuenta_corriente', 'idcuenta_corriente');
}
```

Luego en mi `controller` hago la consulta la cual me trae correctamente los datos pero sólo necesito sumar el monto,  osea una columna de pago corriente

```
$cuentaProveedor = Persona::with('cuentaCorriente.pagoCorriente')->where('cliente_proveedor','proveedor')->get();
```

osea en mi `view` tengo asi:

```
{{$cuentaProveedor->cuentaCorriente->pagoCorriente->sum('monto')}}}
```

Pero me tira error.  **¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?**

Comment: ¿Qué error aparece?